# MySQL Timezone in ClearDB, Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I already changed my Heroku app timezone by using the following command:

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```

I noted that the timezone in my app did change, but when I put A `SELECT NOW()` command, the timezone **didn't change**.

When I enter the following command:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

It appears "SYSTEM" as a result.

**How can MYSQL reflect the change and be in the same timezone as my Heroku app?**

Comment: Heroku's databases don't run on the same instances. Setting `TZ` won't affect MySQL/PostgreSQL at all.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you stick to UTC for both app and database, and do the conversion in the application itself. Barring that, you can issue a query when you first connect to the database, `SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';`. This will set it **for the individual database session**. I don't believe you can change it globally, as they're shared instances.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz. I can't use the following command inside MySQL "SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00'", it throws me that I don't have enough privileges. Do you have a suggestion on how to change it?

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you, will try doing that.

Comment: Try SESSION instead off GLOBAL `SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00'`..

Comment: @Andrés As I noted, you likely won't have privileges to `SET GLOBAL`, as it'd affect all the other users on that shared database server.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz. I submitted my comment with the GLOBAL statement before reading yours. I will try doing the same command but with the SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

As the user ceejayoz noted, this is because Heroku's databases don't run on the same instances. Will mark this question as closed.